# Spring reactive : mixing RestTemplate & WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two endpoints : `/parent` and `/child/{parentId}`
I need to return list of all `Child`

```
public class Parent {
  private long id;
  private Child child;
}

public class Child {
  private long childId;
  private String someAttribute;
}
```

However, call to `/child/{parentId}` is quite slow, so Im trying to do this:

1. Call `/parent` to get 100 parent data, using asynchronous RestTemplate
2. For each parent data, call `/child/{parentId}` to get detail
3. Add the result call to `/child/{parentId}` into `resultList`
4. When 100 calls to `/child/{parentId}` is done, return `resultList`

I use wrapper class since most endpoints returns JSON in format :

```
{
  "next": "String",
  "data": [
    // parent goes here
  ]
}
```

So I wrap it in this

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
  private List<T> data;
  private String next;
}
```

I wrote this code, but the resultList always return empty elements.
What is the correct way to achieve this?

```
public List<Child> getAllParents() {
    var endpointParent = StringUtils.join(HOST, "/parent");
    var resultList = new ArrayList<Child>();

    var responseParent = restTemplate.exchange(endpointParent, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<Parent>>() {
            });

    responseParent.getBody().getData().stream().forEach(parent -> {
        var endpointChild = StringUtils.join(HOST, "/child/", parent.getId());
        // async call due to slow endpoint child
        webClient.get().uri(endpointChild).retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<Child>>() {
                }).map(wrapper -> wrapper.getData()).subscribe(children -> {
                    children.stream().forEach(child -> resultList.add(child));
                });
    });

    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `subscribe` on a reactive type starts the processing but returns immediately; you have no guarantee at that point that the processing is done. So by the time your snippet is calling `return resultList`, the `WebClient` is probably is still busy fetching things.

You're better off discarding the async resttemplate (which is now deprecated in favour of WebClient) and build a single pipeline like:

```
public List<Child> getAllParents() {
    var endpointParent = StringUtils.join(HOST, "/parent");
    var resultList = new ArrayList<Child>();

   Flux<Parent> parents = webClient.get().uri(endpointParent)
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(ResponseWrapper.class)
            .flatMapMany(wrapper -> Flux.fromIterable(wrapper.data));

    return parents.flatMap(parent -> {
      var endpointChild = StringUtils.join(HOST, "/child/", parent.getId());
      return webClient.get().uri(endpointChild).retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<Child>>() {
                }).flatMapMany(wrapper -> Flux.fromIterable(wrapper.getData()));
    }).collectList().block();
}
```

By default, the `parents.flatMap` operator will process elements with some concurrency (16 by default I believe). You can choose a different value by calling another variant of the `Flux.flatMap` operator with a chosen concurrency value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer.It returns list, but the result is mistmatch. Flux does not have `block()`, so I assume I can use `blockLast()` or `blockFirst()`? Let's just say, I have 10 parents, each with 10 child. Now when I use `blockLast()` or `blockFirst()`, only 10 elements returned from one parent.

Comment: The requirement is actually : if call to `/child` took two seconds each (to returns list of 10 Childs for single calls), and I have 10 parents, which means 10 calls to `/child/parentId`, what should I code to call the child -maybe in parallel- and join those 100 childs. But I don't have to wait 20 seconds? (10 calls each 2 second). Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just need small adjustment on `bodyToMono(ResponseWrapper.class)`. It should be `.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<Parent>>() `