# Efficient way to do async call in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a two endpoints : `/parent` and `/child/{parentId}`
Both will return List

Let's assume each call will take two seconds.
So If I call `/parent` and got 10 parents in list, and I want to call and populate each child, I will need 22 seconds in total (2 secs for `/parent`, 10 times `/child/{parentId}` with 2 seconds each)

In Spring and Java 10, I can use `RestTemplate`, combined with `Future` to do async call.
In this snippet, `/slow-five` is call to parent, while `/slow-six` is call to child.

```
public List<Child> runSlow2() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    var futures = new ArrayList<Future<List<Child>>>();
    var result = new ArrayList<Child>();

    System.out.println("Start took (ms) : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    var responseFive = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8005/api/r/slow-five", HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<Parent>>() {
            });

    for (var five : responseFive.getBody().getData()) {
        // prepare future
        var future = executor.submit(new Callable<List<Child>>() {

            @Override
            public List<Child> call() throws Exception {
                var endpointChild = "http://localhost:8005/api/r/slow-six/" + five.getId();

                var responseSix = restTemplate.exchange(endpointChild, HttpMethod.GET, null,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<Child>>() {
                        });

                return responseSix.getBody().getData();
            }
        });

        futures.add(future);
    }

    for (var f : futures) {
        try {
            result.addAll(f.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Before return took (ms) : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

    return result;
}
```

Ignore the ResponseWrapper. It's just wrapper class like this

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
    private List<T> data;
    private String next;
}
```

The code works fine, It took about 3-4 seconds to gather all childs from 10 parents. But I don't think it's efficient.
Furthermore, Spring 5 has `WebClient` that should be able to do this kind of thing.
However, I can't find any sample for this kind of hierarchial calls. Most samples on `WebClient` involves only simple call to single endpoint without dependency.
Any clue how can I use WebClient to achieve same things? Calling multiple `/child` asynchronously and merge the result?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried giving the `ExecutorService ` more threads? Since this is i/o work, it should benefit from more threads than processors are available, since the network is the bottleneck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring reactive : mixing RestTemplate & WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757377/spring-reactive-mixing-resttemplate-webclient)

Answer (score 0):

> It took about 3-4 seconds to gather all childs from 10 parents.

I think we should make clear what slows down the method runSlow2().
 Your method makes multiple calls to endpoints. You improve performance by executing calls parallelism and gather results from them. 
I don't think restTemplate is slow, nothing wrong with your code, maybe your endpoints are slow.
One improvement can be instead of making multiple calls parallelism to /child/{parentId}, you can introduce a new endpoint which accept a list of parentId.
Hope it help.

Comment: What are you talking about, all the endpoint calls are run in parallel by putting them into futures and later retrieving them via `get() `.

Comment: The actual endpoint `/parent` and `/child` are external endpoint. I can't control or enhance them. The snippet is just for example